# Environment Variables in an isomorphic JS app: Webpack find & replace?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle an isomorphic JS app ([based on this example](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example)) so that the browser runs the same code as the server. Everything is running smoothly except I have a `config.js` with some settings which are pulled in from environment variables on the server:

```
module.exports = {
  servers:
    auth: process.env.AUTH_SERVER_URL,
    content: process.env.CONTENT_SERVER_URL
  }
}
```

On the server this is grand, but when webpack renders this for the client `process` is empty and this doesn't work.

I'm hoping there's a kind of 'find and replace' webpack plugin that will replace them with their content in that file alone?

```
"…config.js content…".replace(/process\.env\.([a-z0-9_]+)/, function(match, varName) {
  return process.env[varName];
})
```

Comment: I've found [envify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify-loader) but I'm having a hard time configuring it.

Comment: There is an plugin, which allows to whitelist environment var which should be inlined: `new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["AUTH_SERVER_URL", "CONTENT_SERVER_URL"])`

Comment: The problem is that the machine that build the environment is not always the one that one that run the code (this is true in our case). One way is to put them in `global` and in `window` in the HTML but it is not my favorite solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`,
use the following `preLoaders` (or `postLoaders`),

```
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "transform?envify" },
    ]
  }
```

Another way using the `webpack.DefinePlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': Object.keys(process.env).reduce(function(o, k) {
        o[k] = JSON.stringify(process.env[k]);
        return o;
      }, {})
    })
]
```

**NOTE**: The old method using `envify-loader` was deprecated:

> **DEPRECATED**: use [transform-loader](https://github.com/webpack/transform-loader) + [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) instead.

Comment: Out of interest, on what grounds is the other method deprecated?

Comment: Whatever was being done in `envify-loader` was just a wrapper. Discussion [here](https://github.com/mjohnston/envify-loader/issues/1).

Answer (score 16):

Note that using the `DefinePlugin` as suggested in the accepted answer is potentially a dangerous action as it completely exposes `process.env`. As Tobias commented above there's actually a plugin `EnvironmentPlugin` that does exactly this with an added whitelisting ability, using `DefinePlugin` internally.

In your `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
      'NODE_ENV',
      'WHITELISTED_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE'
    ])
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how webpack knows to replace `NODE_ENV` with `"production"`, for example. With envify you need to tell it with what to replace `NODE_ENV` -- how does this work?

Comment: Webpack doesn't really replace any values here, it will inject whatever you whitelist from process.env into your code with whatever values already set. You need to set your environment variables yourself before the compilation starts. From the command line `NODE_ENV=production webpack`, or maybe in your Webpack config file `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'`.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah; looks like [envify-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify-loader) was the easy solution.

I just added the following to my webpack loaders:

```
{
  test: /config\.js$/, loader: "envify-loader"
}
```

And the `config.js` (and only that file) is modified to include any referenced environment variables statically :)

Comment: This method is deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

I needed a way to use the env variables set on the machine that is running the code, no the env variables of the machine building the app.

I do not see a solution for this yet. This is what I did.

In `publicEnv.js`:

```
// List of the env variables you want to use on the client. Careful on what you put here!
const publicEnv = [
  'API_URL',
  'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
  'GA_ID'
];

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const base = (isBrowser ? window.__ENV__ : process.env) || {};

const env = {};
for (const v of publicEnv) {
  env[v] = base[v];
}
export default env;
```

In the HTML template file of the page I have:

```
import publicEnv from 'publicEnv.js';

...

<script>
  window.__ENV__ = ${stringify(publicEnv)};

  // Other things you need here...
  window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${stringify(initialState)};
</script>
```

So now I can get the value of the env variable on both frontend and backend with:

```
import publicEnv from 'publicEnv.js';

...

console.log("Google Analytic code is", publicEnv.GA_ID);
```

I hope it can help.