# Setting environment configuration in a TypeScript app with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have gone through several solutions including the ones listed here:

- [Environment Variables in an isomorphic JS app: Webpack find & replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717819/environment-variables-in-an-isomorphic-js-app-webpack-find-replace)
- [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

I am used to using something like [`gulp-replace-task`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task) to find and update a `config` file for the app to replace things like `@@SERVER_URL` with something set from the environment.

That way I can do `export SERVER_URL=something` or run the script with `SERVER_URL=something gulp build` to set the configuration.

I've tried all of the following:

#### Using the `transform-loader` plus `envify`

This is a suggestion from the first question, but it does not work for me because of:

```
Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
at throwError (ngapp/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2823:21)
```

Seems like `esprima-fb` is using an `import` declaration that Webpack can't use for some reason or another. [The project](https://github.com/facebookarchive/esprima) is no longer maintained either, so this may be the wrong road to go down.

#### Using `DefinePlugin`

I've added:

```
module: {plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({"process.env.SERVER_URL": "something"})]}
```

This seems to be ignored, or at least `process.env.SERVER_URL` does not get interpolated in my typescript files. When I `console.log(process.env)`, it emits an empty object.

#### Setting using `--define` for webpack

I updated my `npm` script:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --define process.env.SERVER_URL=${SERVER_URL}"
```

However this just ends up replacing `process.env.SERVER_URL` in my code with a literal `"${SERVER_URL}"` rather than being interpolated in the npm script.

Is there a simple / convenient (or at this point really any) way to use environment variables in TypeScript apps built with Webpack?

---

My Webpack setup is essentially what is listed [in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

Comment: Have you tried `EnvironmentPlugin` mentioned in the second question you listed?

Comment: testing with console.log at runtime won't work with DefinePlugin. It appears  use string matching to replace the code that gets served. Fornew webpack.DefinePlugin({MY_CONSTANT: JSON.stringify("something")} will literally replace the text MY_CONSTANT with "something" in all your TypeScript files.